# Programming several AVR MCUs simultaneously? (with parallel)

Tags: avr, programmer, parallel, isp

I was able to program three ATMEGA32 simultaneously using ISP.

[image: ATMEGA32]

[image: vefriy]

In your opinion, can I program several AVRs at once with parallel? Unfortunately, I do not have a parallel programmer. Can you test it for me?

I don't know, how it's work? I already thought it shouldn't work! How many MCU can I program together?

Comment: I made some edits, but your question is still somewhat chaotic. You may want to ask explicitly about parallel programming and why your multi-SPI programming method worked.

Comment: Haha, these pictures are from 1980. Cool!

Comment: The problem I see is the internal oscillator that runs free at around 1, 2 or 8MHz and I know by own experience that it jitters *a lot*. This means that the AVR output signals will not be in sync. I don't know what that means for programming, but it doesn't sound reliable.

Comment: @dext0rb oh! dextorb!  :D!

Comment: I do not know if this is still active after all that time but hey ccheck this link: from adafruit.
https://learn.adafruit.com/mass-avr-isp-programmer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use sufficiently conservative timings and ignore the `MISO` pins on all but one of the MCUs, it’s possible that you could *program* them in parallel. However, I don’t see how you could *verify* them in parallel unless you break out every `MISO` pin onto a separate pin and somehow check them all.

Unless you have a need to program truly massive numbers of MCUs, the whole thing strikes me as more effort than it’s worth.